# Why is $v/\|v\|$ not a unit vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have a homework question that is seriously stumping me. It was a true/false statement.
The statement is

> "If $v$ is any vector in an inner product space $V$, then $v/\|v\|$ is a unit vector"

and according to my professor, the statement is false.
Isn't dividing a vector by its length the very definition of normalizing a vector?

**Edit: Thanks everyone! I didn't even consider the null vector.**

Comment: The statement as it is does not exclude $v=0$ .

Comment: maybe the thing you have to note is that this doesn't make sense if $v=0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\vec{v} = 0$, then:
$$\frac{1}{\|v\|}\vec{v} = ?$$

The norm, $\| \|$, is normally $>0$ except only if $v = 0$.

Comment: "If you write $||v||$ instead of $\|v\|$, then you'll have "the norm $||||$", with four equally spaced vertical lines, rather than "the norm $\|\|$".  I changed it to the latter, which is standard usage.  Notice the conspicuous diffence between $||a||||b||$ and $\|a\|\|b\|$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 8):

It's not true for **any** vector. There is at least one vector for which it's undefined : the null vector.

Now, it's true that for every non null vector, it's an unit vector

Answer (score 3):

I consider your professor's question to be badly stated.

The expression

> If $v$ is any vector in an inner product space $V$, then $v/\|v\|$ is a unit vector.

can be translated into symbols as

$$\forall v \in V:  \left\| \frac{v}{\|v\|}  \right\| =1. \tag{1}\label{first}$$

If your professor has `true/false` as possible answers then either \eqref{first} is `true` or its negation, which is

$$ \exists v \in V:  \left\| \frac{v}{\|v\|}  \right\| \ne 1. \tag{2}\label{second}$$

Now note that \eqref{second} isn't true either since it "breaks" if you try to plug in $0\in V$ (for one can't divide by zero).

So while one can see what was meant by the question and that your professor meant `false` to be the correct answer, I, being a student, am always somewhat peeved when I see something like this on an exam.

Comment: I agree. The statement isn't false; its ill-typed.

Answer (score 1):

Great question.  Yes, the zero vector is the counter-example.

I want to also add that the **zero matrix** is good to remember when needing counter-examples --  it has been a good one, especially for exams, from my own experience.